# How to view photo ratings done in Capture One in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, photos

I rated my photos by Capture One and would like to view these "stars rating" in Finder. I only found a way to shows only colour tags, not the ratings. How can I enable the star rating display (as Windows Explorer does for instance)?

Answer (score 1):

Capture One [& many other photo apps] usually store that data in a sidecar XMP file along with RAW edits etc, not in the photo itself. Usually, only another similar app will be able to read them, by associating the sidecars with the originals.
I don't ever edit in Capture One, I only ever use it as a tethering solution then hand off to ViewNX, so I've not tested which other apps can read those particular XMP files.

For comparison, I've never found anything which can read the star ratings from Nikon's ViewNX-i other than other Nikon apps.